# Is logging framework usuable in moodle blocks?

Tags: php, moodle

I have been working to add a record in mdl_log table whenever an user clicks a button in a block and actually redirected to a moodle page. I was reading on some of the solutions where one mentioned that work on logging framework is still going on. I can see it is pretty much tied to course id and my block is not related to any course. I was wondering how to trigger an event that would actually write an entry in mdl_log table.

Comment: Thanks to someone, who stalks my stackoverflow moodle questions, and upvotes it, probably I know, you sit just behind me ;)

Comment: Which version of Moodle are you using?

Comment: I am using Moodle 2.8